# Pandas text pattern matching 80% to 90% and delete matched

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have a table with same product with different colors.
The quantity is different for each.
However, the format is so different for the product.

```
PROD                        QUAN
product abcdefg (white)     20
product abcdefg blue color  30
product abcdefg - pink      20
product zy                  80
```

I want to -

- Match atleast 80%-90% of the text in PROD and
- Delete the ones with Higher Quantity
- Keep only One of the three products and delete the rest

The final output expected is

```
PROD                        QUAN
product abcdefg (white)     20
product zy                  80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Match atleast 80%-90% of the text in PROD and

How about 70%?

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'PROD': {0: 'product abcdefg (white)',
  1: 'product abcdefg blue color',
  2: 'product abcdefg - pink',
  3: 'product zy'},
 'QUAN': {0: 20, 1: 30, 2: 20, 3: 80}})


# slice at (say 70%)...
cutOff = round((len(df.loc[0,'PROD'])/100) * 70)

df['PROD2'] = df['PROD'].str.slice(stop=cutOff)

df = df[df['QUAN'] == df.groupby('PROD2')['QUAN'].transform('min')]

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['PROD2','QUAN'], keep="first").reset_index(drop=True)

del df['PROD2']

print(df)

    PROD                        QUAN
0   product abcdefg (white)     20
1   product zy                  80
```

Comment: this is great. I truly appreciate. Thank you very much.